# update the yAxis min value and tooltip dynamically in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am unable to update the chart's yaxis min tick to 0 dynamically. I tried to built a generic chart for all the types of charts i am working on. some of the charts have negative values so i need negative axis and column chart with percentages, don't have negative axis. I'm setting a parameter in the javascript code to see if its a percent or not, then show the min tick for y-axis according to it. Also the tooltip has to be dynamic, which i am not able to achieve. I am missing something in my current approcach
This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaPG9/28/)

```
$(function () {
    var isPercent = 'true';
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        series: [{
            name: '1',
            data: [10, 31, 100, 89, 92, 12]
        }, {
            name: '2',
            data: [90, 69, 0, 11, 8, 88]
        }, {
            name: '3',
            data: [90, 69, 0, -11, 8, 88],
            type: 'line'
        }]
    },function(chart){
        if(isPercent === 'true') {
                chart.options.yAxis['min'] = 0;
                console.log(chart.options.yAxis['min']);
            }


    });
});
```

Comment: Setting the min of yAxis doesn't make the data to change. You should work with your data. Search your data for negative values and set them to 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    var isPercent = 'true';
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            yAxis:{
                min : (isPercent === 'true' ? 0 : null),
                labels:{
                    format:(isPercent === 'true' ? '{value}%' : '{value}'),
                }
            },
            tooltip:{
                pointFormat:'<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:,.0f}' + (isPercent === 'true' ? '%' : '') + '</b><br/>'
            },
            series: [{
                name: '1',
                data: [10, 31, 100, 89, 92, 12]
            }, {
                name: '2',
                data: [90, 69, 0, 11, 8, 88]
            }, {
                name: '3',
                data: [90, 69, 0, -11, 8, 88],
                type: 'line'
            }]
        });
    });
```

This is for the min. *updated:* http://jsfiddle.net/CaPG9/31/

Like this?

Comment: if isPercent is true, then I have to show `%` at the end of the value, otherwise just leave the number as is without `%` symbol.

Comment: `pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'` I have this